# Using <script> within a leaflet marker popup

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet, script-tag

This is going to be a very simple question.

Is there a way of using `<script> .... </script>` within a Leaflet marker popup ? If not, is there a way around it (ie is there a way to save what the script returns and implement that return in the marker popup) ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the script?

Comment: I am trying to display a star rating using the RateYo plugin.

Comment: This one ? https://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be mixing 2 actions: loading the script and calling the `rateYo()` function

Loading the script has nothing particular ...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
```

Then you must call the function when the popup opens:

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap)
    .bindPopup("I am a popup.<div id=\"rateYo\"></div>");
marker.id = something;

marker.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    // the id of the clicked marker is e.target.id
    // retrieve the rating for this id and use it in the rateYo() call
    $("#rateYo").rateYo({
    rating: 3.6,
    starWidth: "15px"
  });
```

here is an example: https://plnkr.co/8PZIgd2g4Da6AHhWvC2o

Comment: Thanks I will try this. The only issue I can see (without doing any tests) is the fact I have 300+ markers on the map and that I would like a different RateYo rating for each marker (making this more complex than I first thought).

Comment: The idea is to name your marker with an id that you can retrieve in the event callback (look at my updated answer). I use this technique extensively in this example: https://github.com/franceimage/franceimage.github.io (look at map/explore.js)